# Network connected iOS app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I Am building a iOS app that purpose is to allow a user to search google books, or another book database, and receive a formatted return in a given format.

I am having troubles finding out how I would query the server and get a return in my app. And also with using a UISearchbar in order to make the search happen across the web instead of in app itself. I am quite sure my answer lies with a NSurl string somehow but I am having a difficult time finding out how to implement this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! 
Sorry if it is a simple question I am very new to development, let alone iOS development...I am a graphic designer by trade...

Answer (score 3):

Go look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's a third-party library for HTTP client functions that is WAY simpler and more feature-rich than the built-in stuff.

EDIT: Thanks for the comment @Nils Munch, as all the places I've recommended ASI would be impossible for me to find without the occasional comment.

ASIHTTPRequest absolutely IS lovely. It's also deprecated by its developer, who recommends using a different package. It's a shame, but there it is: new projects should almost certainly NOT use ASI. AFNetworking seems like a popular choice.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).